# javascript function call doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have some php, html and JS code:

```
$files = getDirectoryList("/home/uploads/");

foreach($files as $file)
{
    ?>
    <input type="submit" onclick="writetofile("<?php echo $file; ?>")" value="Work " />     
    <?php 
    echo $file;

}
```

When I click on "Work" the `writetofile` doesn't get called which is defined at top in HTML head tag script. Why?

Comment: Could we see writetofile perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have incorrectly quoted the string inside the JavaScript function call. Change them from double to single quotes.  (This assumes `$file`  is being passed to the function as a string, and isn't supposed to have been defined somewhere in JavaScript as a symbol).

```
<input type="submit" onclick="writetofile('<?php echo $file; ?>')" value="Work " />
```